# How to check success of HubConnection.StartAsync in SignalR for ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-2.0, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

Using SignalR for ASP.NET Core 2.0, Client side (1.0.0-alpha2-final), C# VS2017.

To connect the code is:
`await hubConnection.StartAsync();`
since this is an `await` for a `void` how can we test if the client did manage to connect ?  In my tests I have a breakpoint on the server side in `public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()` but that breakpoint is not *always* hit therefore I know that ***sometimes*** the client does not connect. Or perhaps it **did** connect but `OnConnectedAsync()` was not triggered?

How can the client knows it succeeded in establishing the connection?

Thanks

Edit: More info. It **does** fire `OnConnectedAsync()` when using `localhost` (debugging in VS); it **does not** fire `OnConnectedAsync()` when connecting through ngrok. Maybe this is something to do with proxy/CORS, I am not familiar with.

Edit: It appears that the Client **does** indeed connect because if I change the URL to a non existing one it gives a 404. So it appears that the problem is that `OnConnectedAsync()` does not fire when the client connects through ngrok but does fire when connected directly to localhost.

Answer (score 2):

`StartAsync` is not a `void` method but returns a `Task`. If the client does not connect `StartAsync` throws (returns a faulted task) otherwise the async call will complete without an error (returns a completed task) after the client is successfully connected.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for pointing this out.  To be more clear my problem is rather as I explained in the 2nd Edit of my post: The StartAsync *does* throw when the end point (URL) *does not* exist. When the proper URL is supplied it *does not* throw BUT on the server the `OnConnectedAsync()` *does* fire when I use localhost but *does not* fire when I connect through a proxy such as ngrok. Why?