# Use SignalR as both a Hub and a Client in two ASP.NET Core 2.1 Razor web apps

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have 2 ASP.NET Core Razor web apps. Each app will be using SignalR to communicate with web app clients and mobile clients. Because of my intended use, I have setup both web apps as Hub and Client, where the Client is using the .NET SignalR Client. Each of the 2 web apps have the following:

```
        static internal HubConnection Connection; // In the Startup class

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

            Connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                 // Where the URL is for the OTHER web app
                .WithUrl("https://localhost:44386/NotificationHub")
                .Build();
        }
```

Each project also has a NotificationHub class, derived from Hub, in the Hubs folder.

In the Startup ConfigureServices method in each app I have as the last statement:

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

In the Startup Configure method in each app I have the following immediately before the call to UseMvc:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/NotificationHub");
});
```

In each of the NotificationHub classes I have:

```
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
```

So, I am unsure how to initially connect from one Client to a Hub and I am also unsure if I am using the URL correctly.

Comment: you want to connect using .net client or using js ? to post the answer

Answer (score 2):

For using js Client :

1) Install signalr npm : `npm install @aspnet/signalr`

2) Add the reference in required page

3) Add Connection Object code

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/NotificationHub")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();
connection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
```

4) Call your require method

```
connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
```

For .Net Client

1) install nuget: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client`

2)

```
 HubConnection connection  = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("https://localhost:44386/NotificationHub")
            .Build();     

 await connection.StartAsync();

 await connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", 
                    "user", "message");
```

you can start the connection with button click or on sending message

You can find more details in below link :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I should have mentioned, I want to use the .NET client in both apps

Comment: OK, but where do I put the call: await connection.StartAsync(); ?

Comment: you can add on event handler or just in ctor if you want always to be connected

Comment: I managed to get the Hub and the Client working in one direction so far. I haven't yet tested running a Hub AND a Client in each web app. An obvious question arises thou - How do I determine if the StartAsync actually connected?

Comment: Glad to help here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056690/how-to-check-success-of-hubconnection-startasync-in-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0 ... dont forget to mark if saved your day :)))